# How to disable notify on "screen -D -R"

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm running screen -D -R (with optionally using -S name), and it works great, but has one problem - when given screen doesn't exist earlier, i get notification "New screen...", and irritating wait.

How can I disable this particular notification?

Comment: It's just a notification. It's not hanging, you can start typing, the notification will disappear and everything starts working.

Comment: I know, but it's annoying. And was hoping that there is a way to remove it. Besides - it actually *stops* shell from running - i.e. shell prompt shows only after notification is gone (whether it's timeout, or me pressing some key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this behavior is hard-coded in the source: the same test is used to determine whether to emit the “New screen...” notification and to determine whether to attach to a running session. (In the screen 4.0.3 source, `(rflag && (rflag & 1) == 0)` in `attacher.c` and `screen.c` — `rflag` is 1 for `-r` plus 2 for each `-R`.)

If you're willing to recompile, the patch is trivial: remove the line that displays the message from `screen.c`.

You can make the message go away by typing something. If you don't want to type a key that will reach the application inside the screen window, you can type `` C-a ` `` or some other unbound key.

A simple workaround of sorts is to immediately detach the screen session (either with `C-a d` or with the `detach` command in the `screenrc` file; `-m` on the command line doesn't work for this when `-R` is also specified), then attach to it again (e.g. by running the same command again).

A really kludgy but fully automated workaround is to include the following lines in the `screenrc` file to skip messages initially and reenable them one second later:

```
msgwait 0
screen -t post_initialization 39 sh -c 'sleep 1; screen -X msgwait 5'
```

(39 is the highest possible window number, it's a compile-time option (`MAXWIN`).)

Note that both workarounds will hide any message `screen` chooses to display when it starts, not just the useless “New screen...” one.

Comment: Finally solved it this way: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/08/30/tips-n-tricks-using-gnu-screen-as-shell/ but your answer is the most informative.

Comment: the post_initialization method did not work for me. I have gnome terminal running screen -R as its startup command, and it just starts and immediately exits.

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same problem. In the latest version of screen, you can specify the `-q` flag to quiet screen, and keep it from showing.

The [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/screen.c#n1445) shows

```
if (rflag && (rflag & 1) == 0 && !quietflag)
```

so I don't know where Gilles found that, or when it was changed.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: @interestinglythere Why is it not correct? It works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am quite late on the scene, but I just had the same problem.
I resolved it by not using -D -R, but just -S.
So `$ screen -S myScreenName`. This starts the screen right away...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your *.screenrc* file:

```
startup_message off
msgwait 1
```

The latter will cause all the screen messages being visible only for 1 second - that maybe annoyingly short other times, though.

Comment: I already have startup_message off, and msgwait - well, it's shorter, but it's still there. I could set it to 0, but then it would influence all other notifications as well :(